# Adjacent Faces in Three.js

Tags: javascript, 3d, three.js

Is there a more efficient way of finding adjacent faces than searching through the list of faces looking for faces that share vertices? I have a part of a problem that requires knowing which faces are adjacent, and ideally it would be performed during the render loop. Searching through a massive list will bog down performance.

Comment: Maybe `WireframeHelper.js` or `EdgesHelper.js` will give you some ideas.

Comment: Hi HighSkyd, I am in the process of writing code to compute an adjacency list for three.js meshes... looks like you already did the same. Is your code available?

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is within a repo from a previous job that I no longer have access to. I've reached out to a few former coworkers to see if I can get access to this specific code. Hopefully, I'll be able to retrieve the code and upload it to my GitHub. I'll try to post an update as soon as possible, but I wouldn't expect it before next week.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are going to be searching for adjacency faces very often you should invest time in building a data structure that will help to do this efficiently. The Half-edge data structure (http://www.flipcode.com/archives/The_Half-Edge_Data_Structure.shtml) comes to mind and there are several others. Take a look at http://www.cs.rpi.edu/~cutler/classes/advancedgraphics/S09/lectures/02_Adjacency_Data_Structures.pdf

Comment: I originally had used a different data structure, and implementing the Half-edge greatly improved my performance. Thanks so much!